# Read a directory in a jar file

Tags: java, arrays, resources, jar, directory

Been trying to get this working all day but it always returns in errors and even after all the research i've done i'm still clueless

here's the method, the line that's currently returning with an error is

```
File file = new File( url.toURI() );
```

i'm unsure what it is that i have to do to make it work

```
public void preloadModelsTwo() {
    String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    try {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("."+ slash +"Patches" + slash+"Models"+slash);
        File file = new File( url.toURI() );
        File[] fileArray = file.listFiles();
        for(int y = 0; y < fileArray.length; y++) {
            String s = fileArray[y].getName();
            if (s != "") {
                byte[] buffer = readFile("."+ slash +"Patches" + slash+"Models"+slash+""+s);
                Model.method460(buffer, Integer.parseInt(getFileNameWithoutExtension(s)));
                //System.out.println("Read model: " + s);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("error with secondary model screening");
        E.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

all i'm aware of is that the stuff needs to be treated as resources, however i'm unsure what i need to change to do so, i'm sure i've made all the neccessary changes however it's still not working

any help appreciated

EDIT:

i've been messing around with this and this is the new method that seems to be working pretty well except it can't read

```
public String removeNonDigits(String text) {
    int length = text.length();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char ch = text.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            buffer.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public JarEntry entry;
public void preloadModelsTwo() {
    String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    try {
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("SilabGarza.jar");
for(Enumeration em = jarFile.entries(); em.hasMoreElements();) {  
    String s= em.nextElement().toString();  
    if(s.contains(".dat")){
        entry = jarFile.getJarEntry(s);
        InputStream input = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
        System.out.println("input = "+input);
        //byte[] buffer = readFile(s);
        String s2 = removeNonDigits(s);
        //Model.method460(buffer, Integer.parseInt(s2));
        System.out.println("Found: "+s);
        System.out.println("formd: "+s2);

        input.close();
    }  
}
jarFile.close();

    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("error with secondary model screening");
        E.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

not sure how i'm suppose to read it (right now i have the reading commented out)
any clues anyone?

Comment: Could you post the error that you get?

Comment: its just a null pointer exception leading to line 501 (the line with url.toURI() in it)

Comment: OK. Have you checked if the value of url is null? You could even check each part of the expression used to set url to see which part is null

Comment: i'm thinking it has to do with the directory it's trying to read

Comment: True, but I think you should check whether url is null and why

Comment: it's null because it's not the right directory ._.

Comment: Where does Patches/Models/ locate? under project root directory project/ or the actual package directory project/src/com/package/?

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong to use File.separator here. A resource is identified by a URL, not a filename, and URLs only have forward slashes.

You are then wrong to turn that URL into a File. It may be a URL that points inside a JAR at a remote location.

Comment: please look at the edit i've just applied to the main post, hopefully that'll be more informative

Comment: @TravisWhitmarsh `ZipEntry` has an API. Don't just call `toString()` and hope for the best. And it doesn't read because you don't *do* any reading. You get the input stream but then you just close it. `InputStream` also has an API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(/* resource name */);
final URL resolve = org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.resolve(url);
File file = new File( resolve.getPath());
```

**EDIT:** Oh, I just saw, you getting your `url` as `null`. Remember that `getResource("resource name")` looks for the resource in `classpath`. So your `resource name` should be `/package/path/of/resourceName.extenstion`

e.g. `/com/kjain/widget/identifier/views/view.jpg`